# Why will network manager not allow me save my VPN settings?

Tags: unity, network-manager, openvpn

I am trying to configure am OpenVPN client on my laptop. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

When I open network manager and import the VPN settings from the premade config folder everything takes. The problem is when I try to save the settings, the `save` button at the bottom of the network manager applet is greyed out. Further more when I hover over the button it says `Authenticate to save this connection for all users of this machine`. The problem is I did not check the box `Available to all users` it was already checked and it is also greyed out and won't let me manipulate it.

What is going on? Is this a bug or is there something I am missing?

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: What kind of VPN connection are you setting up?

Comment: OpenVPN using SSL certs

Comment: I will load that option up on my test box tonight if I can and see if there is a bug.

Comment: I tested on two boxes and could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: When you click on the option to edit connections, did it `sudo` you  so you could have permission to edit the connections?

Comment: This must be a bug! If you choose type "password" it should obviously NOT ask for more authentication... Stupid OpenVPN...

Comment: even i had the same problem... cannot save the vpn connection, Save button is highlighted only when I entered the password
And this is a bug in 12.04 not sure , whether it is solved [enter link description here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/990765)

Answer (score 2):

When creating a VPN connection you have to fill out all the required fields before 'save' becomes active. Ensure that you have them all filled out accurately.

Comment: I am very certain the fields are filled out correctly, though I can look to be sure.

Comment: I can understand this being true before 'save' becomes active, but before 'Available to all users' becomes active?

Answer (score 2):

1. Have your service provider send you a zip with your configuration files.
2. Select *Import*.
3. Make sure these fields are populated:

   - User Certificate
   - CA certificate
   - Private Key

Your *Save* button will work then.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, I don't know if I could reproduce it but what I did to get round it was to change the VPN type from certificates(TLS) to password with certificates, then put in some junk text into the two password fields and fiddled with the dropdown for saving the passwords, it then let me save the connection and did store those passwords, that seemed to get it over the problem of not saving the password so I then set it back to certificates(TLS) and put in the real private key password and saved the connection and it worked. This was in a 12.04 virtualbox VM.