# Configure VPN... is greyed out and I cannot edit my VPN settings

Tags: network-manager, vpn

Today I see that my "Configure VPN..." part is greyed out and I have been using several PPTP VPN connections so far and today suddenly this seems to be inactive.

I did the changes in the network manager policy, changes which are mentioned in: [gray button for saving "editing VPN connection" in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135787/gray-button-for-saving-editing-vpn-connection-in-ubuntu-12-04)

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp
sudo network-manager restart
```

But the "Configure VPN..." is still greyed out so I cannot configure my existing VPNs.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. If I upgrade to 14.04, will it work again?

Comment: I have just found a way to configure through clicking System Settings -> Network and then I am able to do. Maybe my Network Manager Icon has got a problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm hitting the same problem on 2 different 12.04 desktop machines.  I'm pretty sure the problem got introduced with the following update that came in on 2/2/2015

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/network-manager-applet

BTW, you can still access the configure side of the VPN by running the "nm-connection-editor" from terminal session.

I don't know why they killed the applet selections for "Configure" and "Disconnect" VPN in the latest update. The change log didn't say anything about that https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/network-manager-applet/+changelog

Comment: Thanks, the hint about running nm-connection-edito on commandline is a real life saver!

Comment: I'd also like to thank for that hint. The good news is that this issue has been fixed too through one of the latest updates. Regards

Comment: 20.04 desktop have the exact same problem. `nm-connection-editor` works!

Answer (score 15):

[Network Manager VPN support is based on a plug-in system.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#VPN_support)

The network-manager-pptp plugin is installed by default.

For OpenVPN, install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Then restart your network-manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Open the `Network connections` program.
Click on `Add`.
Select `PPTP` (or `OpenVPN`) under the VPN section. Fill in your settings and save.

Eventually, you should be able to select a VPN config in the previously greyed out zone.

Comment: Restarting the network-manager was the key.

Comment: I know this is years later, but for me it's actually running `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` that made the "configure VPN" greyed out.