# Unable to create VPN connection in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, vpn

Unable to create VPN connection as the *Save* button is always disabled.

[image: relevant screenshot]

Also, the *Add VPN Connection...* option under *VPN Connections* is disabled.

---

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/833689/340497) solution, I tried accessing the `nm-connection-editor` from the terminal but the problem remained the same. Running the following:

```
$ sudo nm-connection-editor
```

Gave me the following error in the terminal:

```
** Message: vpn: (openvpn,/usr/lib/NetworkManager/VPN/nm-openvpn-service.name) file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-openvpn.so" not found. Did you install the client package?
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
** Message: Cannot save connection due to error: Editor initializing...
** Message: Cannot save connection due to error: Invalid setting VPN: IPSec gateway
```

---

I checked `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy` file as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/157107/340497) solution but the `allow_inactive` was already set to `yes`.

---

How can I resolve this issue? Is there any other way to connect to VPN?

Comment: If you don't mind using other tools, I had similar problems and openconnect worked for me

Comment: @Katu How can I install that? And, will it be useful in my case? Also, I need to mention this, the vpn client that we use in windows is GlobalProtect. I didn't find any alternative for that in linux.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. There was also no `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-openvpn.so` file.

The installation of the `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` package helped.